# create custom category attributes dynamically in admin

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7, categories

I want to create custom category attributes dynamically(through Form) in admin. 
I mean, how can I create custom category attributes through Model/Controller class? 
Please suggest me proper solution to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this free extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-category-customer-and-customer-address-attributes.html) will help you.

I Use it on Magento 1.9

Case: At backend I Created an attribute with Attributecode : category_custom_attribute

To display on category : edit /app/design/frontend/your-template/your-template/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
<?php $category = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<?php $CatCustomAttribute = $category->getCategory_custom_attribute(); ?>
<?php echo $CatCustomAttribute; ?>
```